# Find kernel of a given linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Problem is as follows:

> Find $\ker(T)$ where $T \colon P_2 \to P_2$ is the linear transformation given by $T(a_0 +a_1x+a_2x^2) =a_0+a_1(x+3)+a_2(x+3)^2$.

And here is my take:

I think the first step to find kernel of something is to find a standard matrix. I know $a+bx+cx^2 = [a,b,c]$ and $T([a_0,a_1,a_2]) = [a_0+a_1,2a_1+3a_2]$ but I have no idea how to start this question.

Comment: So find the matrix which does this $$\pmatrix{? & ? & ? \\ ? & ? & ? \\ ? & ? & ?}\pmatrix{a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2} = \pmatrix{a_0 + 3a_1 +9a_2\\ a_1 + 6a_2 \\ a_2}$$

Comment: $T([a_0, a_1, a_2])$ should have three components: $[a_0 + 3a_1 + 9a_2, a_1 + 6a_2, a_2]$.

Comment: @Bye_World how do you find such matrix for that? i assume take inverse of (a0,a1,a2) and multiply from [a0+3a1+9a2,a1+6a2,a2]?

Comment: If I rewrite $\pmatrix{a_0 + 3a_1 +9a_2\\ a_1 + 6a_2 \\ a_2}$ as $\pmatrix{1a_0 + 3a_1 +9a_2\\ 0a_0 + 1a_1 + 6a_2 \\ 0a_0 + 0a_1 + 1a_2}$ does that help you see what the matrix has to be?

Comment: oh yes, then it would just be [1,3,9; 0,1,6; 0,0,1] so from here i have to take rref and find a null space of this matrix and that would be a kernel of T? @Bye_World

Comment: That's correct.  If you'd like to skip some steps you *could* just recognize that that is a full rank matrix (how can I see that?).  Thus by the rank nullity theorem, the dimension of the kernel is $0$.  Thus this transformation has the **trivial kernel** (which is basically what Andre said below, except he doesn't even bother finding the standard matrix).

Comment: so its full rank matrix if and only if all the rows and columns are linearly independent right? how did he or you see that just by looking at the question? and okay. so since its trivial kernal Tv={0} @Bye_World

Comment: Well, you'll probably have to do a few more of these before you recognize that this transformation is full rank *before* finding the standard matrix.  But once you have it just recognize that it's an upper triangular matrix with no $0$'s on the diagonal.  The determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the diagonal entries, so in this case it's nonzero.  That implies that this (square) matrix is full rank.  Sometimes if you can see stuff like that before getting too far into the calculations you can save yourself some work.

Comment: yeah i think i have to do a lot more of problems to understand fully all of this. thank you so much @Bye_World. you really helped a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: we don't need an explicit matrix. Note that $T(1)$, $T(x)$, and $T(x^2)$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel of T: 
$$(a_0+a_1x+a_2*x^2) \in Ker(T) \iff a_0+a_1(x+3)+a_2(x+3)^2=0$$ 
Null polynomial has all coefficients equal 0:$$a_0=0,a_1=0,a_2=0 \to d(T)=0$$ 
Range of T:
$$a_0+a_1(x+3)+a_2(x+3)^2=a_0+xa_1+3a_1+x^2a_2+6xa_2+9a_2$$
$$a_0(1)+a_1(x+3)+a_2(x^2+6x+9)$$
$r(T)=3$
range $= (1,x+3,x^2+6x+9)$ 
$$r(T)+d(T)=dimP_2=3+0=3$$
Linear operator T is injective, surjective and bijective.